# Nhibernate ProjectionList issue

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate

I have issue with a Nhibernate projection list,
It keeps saying it Could not find a setter for property 'Commname' in class 'Label6.Domain.Product' or could not resolve property "pl.commname"
the property "commname" is a part of the object productslangs.

My product object looks like this:

```
  Public Overridable Property Latinname() As System.String
            Get
                Return _Latinname
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As System.String)
                _Latinname = value
            End Set
        End Property
    Public Overridable Property Latinname2() As System.String
        Get
            Return _Latinname2
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As System.String)
            _Latinname2 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overridable Property productslangs() As IList(Of Productslang)
        Get
            Return _productslangstrong text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As IList(Of Productslang))
            _productslangs = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

My criteria looks like this

```
Dim crit As ICriteria = session.CreateCriteria(Of Product)()
                crit.Add(Expression.In(Projections.Property("ID"), aryIds))
                crit.CreateAlias("productslangs", "pl")
                crit.Add(Expression.Eq("pl.LangId", systemSettings.setting.langId))
                crit.SetFetchMode("Product.productslangs", FetchMode.Eager)
                crit.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList() _
                    .Add(Projections.Property("ID"), "ID") _
                .Add(Projections.Property("this.Latinname"), "Latinname") _
                .Add(Projections.Property("this.Matchcode"), "Matchcode") _
                .Add(Projections.Property("this.Price"), "Price") _
                .Add(Projections.Property("this.Productgroup"), "Productgroup") _
                .Add(Projections.Property("this.colorLookUp"), "colorLookUp") _
                .Add(Projections.Property("this.Productsubgroup"), "Productsubgroup") _
                .Add(Projections.Property("pl.Commname"), "Commname")
                )
                list = crit.SetResultTransformer(Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(Of Product)).SetCacheable(True).List(Of Product)()
```

Can anybody tell what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

A projection is a flat representation of your data. When you specify your AliasToBeanTransformer it takes each row and then maps all of the aliases to properties on the type that you specified. Since Product does not have a property called Commname it complains and errors out. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but typically you will want to create a DTO class that has all of the properties specified in your projection list. Then use it as your bean class in the AliasToBeanTransformer specification.

Comment: okay thanks alot I will try that.
The only thing i tried to accomplish was to get some specific fields i needed in a grid.